# AWS, EC2 - CreateTags after RunInstances

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using the .NET SDK and attempting to tag a new instance immediately after creating it - CreateTags immediately after RunInstances.

Most of the time it just works, but occasionally I'll get an error that the instance ID is not valid (subsequently checking in a console or trying again, it is valid).

I understand that with SQS, SDB etc they are 'eventually consistent' and it may be necessary to retry calls (although I believe the SDK does that for you anyway) - but with general calls to create instances I didn't think it was necessary.  What's more I don't think it's a good thing to do; looking for a specific exception and retrying almost infinitely until it works.

If the process of creating an instance and tagging it has to be entered into a distributed workflow with redundant centralised system for polling and retrying I think that's a bad situation!

I can't seem to find anything relevant in the documentation about this.  I figured if I call RunInstances and get a response with an instance ID, that instance ID should be immediately valid for tagging.

My thoughts for possible solutions so far:

- Fixed delay of a few seconds after RunInstances (bad, arbitrary delay)
- Try immediately, else delay 5sec and retry, up to 'n' times (OK but arbitrary)
- Create distributed workflow to handle any chained API calls like this, would need central redundant farm of EC2 instances to manage to be reliable (bad, massively overengineered)
- Find some other explanation where I can call another API method or set something on the request to either call to make it work

Has anyone else experienced this, have any knowledge in that area, etc?

(I've a thread on AWS community forums here, nothing yet: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=80489&tstart=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're right with your first option - it takes a finite, variable time after the call to `RunInstances` before the instance is assigned a reservation identity, begins running, and becomes available for further calls against it.

My control software simply sleeps for 5-second intervals on the launcher thread until the instance enters the `'Running'` state, at which point I can begin issuing other calls.

Comment: Ok but just to confirm - the call returns instantly with an instance ID, but for a short while that instance ID is invalid and useless?  (I don't need the instance to be running, I just want to tag it)

Comment: The InstanceID you get is valid, in the sense that it is the genuine ID that has been assigned to your new instance. However, behind the scenes the Xen Hipervisor is asynchronously constructing the VM and setting it running, so for a brief period after you are given the ID, the instance is not yet actually in existence as far as the rest of the API is concerned and calls to other methods using that ID fail.

Comment: Ok although I am a little confused: the system must record the instance ID *somewhere*, for example to keep track of the AMI it's going to use.  CreateTags would store tag information by instance ID, so I can't imagine why tagging would have anything to do with the status of the VM, the hypervisor or anything else.  I don't suppose you have anything to cite about all of this, I was hoping to find some docs?

Comment: Yes, the InstanceID is registered internally, but I think the key point is that some (perhaps all) Instance-related API calls have a dependency on the internal state of the Instance as the Hipervisor perceives (and publishes) it. For example, if you attempt a call to StopInstances immediately after calling RunInstances, you hit the same race condition as with CreateTags - sometimes it works, and sometimes it pops an exception stating that the InstanceID isn't valid. I've never found any API documentation to clarify this situation, I only have two years of painfully-gained experience. ;)

Comment: Right, ok I can see that, hYpervisor state would be needed in order to stop the instance, guess it's a crappy situation that's oozed into other calls as you say and I'll just have to work around as you do :)  Will leave this question open a little while to see if there's any other input others can give, but not for too long..

Comment: As a seasoned IT specialist, my origins lie in the 80s when the use of IBM system products for virtualisation really started to become affordable. Having cut my teeth on VM/CMS, I know how to spell hIpervisor. ;)

Comment: Ok :), I did do some searching after I saw you spell it Hipervisor twice, but still can't find any reference to it.. Even IBM's pages http://www.vm.ibm.com/ refer to Hypervisor.  Is there a chance that the modern hypervisor is sufficiently different from an 80s hipervisor that they aren't comparable?  (I am just curious now)

Comment: To be fair, there aren't many references left - a sign of how the term has been gradually subverted by the contemporary spelling. :) However, the original Hipervisor and modern Hypervisor are essentially the same thing, being an OS layer above the supervisor (Ring 0) processes of hosted operating systems. Although this reference isn't *about* Hipervisors, it does at least mention the term: http://www.vm.ibm.com/pubs/cp540/syscm.html

Answer (score 1):

The tagging API is implemented on top of the tagging capability of the Xen Hypervisor API, i.e. [see the tags field of a VM in the XenAPI](http://www.xen.org/files/XenCloud/ocamldoc/apidoc.html?c=VM).  In contrast, an instance id corresponds to a entry in the AWS management infrastructure database.  Thus, an instance can be queuing VM creation after the instance id has been returned to the caller.  A side effect of this approach is that some tags cannot be created, as they are reserved for AWS infrastructure.

As @Jonners points out, tagging is not the only API that depends on a VM.  E.g. stopping an instance.  However, "hypervisor" is more likely to avoid trademark disputes as the term is accepted by the NIST, e.g. [Guide to Security for Full Virtualization Technologies](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-125/SP800-125-final.pdf), whereas "hipervisor" has only been attributed to IBM documents.